# Getting data from pivot table using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables with a pivot table

Table user

id | name | email

Table drinks

id | name

Pivot Table user_drinks

id | user_id | drink_id | quantity | price | status

I want to get all users and drinks with status set to 1 and their latest details from the pivot table, that is use the user_Id to get the username and drink_Id to get the drink name then the price and quantity from the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

**In your User Model put this** `//App\User.php`

```
public function drinks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Drink::class)->where('status',1);
    }
```

**In your DrinkModel put this** `//App\Drink.php`

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Drink::class)->where('status',1);
    }
```

Then in your controller you can use this like

```
$users = User::has('drinks')->get(); //to get all the user that has drinks column status set to 1

foreach ($users as $user) {
    //you rest of code
}
```

Comment: thank you Tanvir, it get the users whose status is set to 1 on the pivot table but I need a few other things. I've edited the question.

Comment: then think you have to reconstrcut/re-planned your table. Or forgot about the pivot table. Take a model and put belongsto relationship with User and Drink model. and then ypu can easily get the info. An if you feel confusion and want to try this way let me know.